# Regex for building array of strings that begin with "FT" within a string

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I'm searching a string called poop where a match is:
"FT" followed by up to 6 digits, e.g. FT123456
"FT" followed by any amount of spaces, and up to 6 digits. e.g. FT  3435

Anything can follow the match or precede it, e.g. FT123456

Here is what i have so far

```
string poop = "There must be something to terroir, FT1988 given that expert FT 3245 wine tasters can often identify the region from which a wine comes. But American wine growers have long expressed varying degreesFT26666 of skepticism about this ineffable concept, some dismissing it as unfathomable mysticism and others regarding it as a shrewd >FT34323</a>  marketing ploy to protect the cachet of French wines";


        Regex regex = new Regex(@"FT\d{1,6}");
        Match match = regex.Match(poop);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Value;
        }

        return "tough luck kid";
```

It works fine for returning the first match for FT1988, but doesn't allow spaces, and is not building an array of all the matches, which is what i really want.

The result of the match should be array {FT1988, FT3245, FT26666, FT34323}
Notice it removes any spaces it finds between FT and the following digits. If it finds two of the same value, it should not add the duplicate. The array should be unique values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FT\s*\d{1,6}` and call `Matches()` instead of `Match()`

Something like this should work:

```
string poop = "There must be something to terroir, FT1988 given that expert FT 3245 wine tasters can often identify the region from which a wine comes. But American wine growers have long expressed varying degreesFT26666 of skepticism about this ineffable concept, some dismissing it as unfathomable mysticism and others regarding it as a shrewd >FT34323</a>  marketing ploy to protect the cachet of French wines";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"FT\s*\d{1,6}");
var retVal = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(poop))
    retVal.Add(match.Value.Replace(" ", ""));

return retVal.Distinct().ToList();
```

Think carefully about your requirements. If anything can come before or after the "FT" string, then the regex will also match "FT123456" in "1234567890FT1234567890". That may be what you expect or not.

Comment: return retVal.Distinct().ToList() was required, otherwise worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Good catch! I couldn't actually test it. I'll update for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
^FT[\s\d]{1,6}$
```

Good Luck!